# Make a link within a made link

Tags: php, html, sql, hyperlink

I've been using the method for user generated links to make it something like index.php?s=home

- That worked of course until I tried this index.php?s=user?id=3
  -Is something like that possible because I need it for the $_GET function

I have tried but it is just not working
what do I do? I have a user.php and its being picked up like this index.php?s=user but I also want to sent the get user function withn user.php like user.php?id=3 or whatever
how do I get to combine them two ?

Comment: You need to append other parameters with an ampersand. index.php?s=user&id=3

Comment: please up-vote also. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many parameter you want to add add it through &. but let me warn you get parameter has its own limit and restriction. but it not concern here because you have only two parameter:-

Send it like:-

```
index.php?s=user&id=3&(more value you can append like this)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&` to append additional parsing eg ;

```
index.php?s=user&id=3&myother=works
```